# ext-js with spring mvc integration

Tags: spring-mvc, extjs

I am new to ext-js, I have gone through some sample of extjs. Now I need to integrate my existing Spring MVC application with ext-js. spring controller will act as rest controller and return the json data.

Now, as a best practices, do I need to create 2 different project for front end i.e one for purely ext-js project which does the UX layer and Spring rest controller which get the data from the back end and renders the json data. Or, should I create a single project which having both ext-js and spring-mvc code. Which one is better?
I am using ext-js version 5 and Spring 4.

Comment: I don't see the need to create them as two separate projects I have created Extjs / Grails apps and I find it more comfortable having everything in the same project. Don't really see any benefit in having it in separate projects. Perhaps if that backend is going to be consumed by other clients lets say mobile apps or other systems perhaps in that case it would make sense having it in different projects.

Answer (score 1):

Please find the below Link for the Integration of the Extjs with Spring MVC,Hibernate.

[Ext JS 4 Spring MVC CRUD example](http://java.dzone.com/articles/extjs-spring-mvc-3-and)